# Newton's method: order of statements in loop

Tags: python, loops, debugging, while-loop, newtons-method

I'm trying to implement Newton's method for fun in Python but I'm having a problem conceptually understanding the placement of the check.

A refresher on Newton's method as a way to approximate roots via repeated linear approximation through differentiation:

[image: Newton's Method]

I have the following code:

```
# x_1 = x_0 - (f(x_0)/f'(x_0))
# x_n+1 - x_n = precision

def newton_method(f, f_p, prec=0.01):
    x=1
    x_p=1
    tmp=0

    while(True):
        tmp = x
        x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))
        if (abs(x-x_p) < prec):
            break;
        x_p = tmp

    return x
```

This works, however if I move the `if` statement in the loop to after the `x_p = tmp` line, the function ceases to work as expected. Like so:

```
# x_1 = x_0 - (f(x_0)/f'(x_0))
# x_n+1 - x_n = precision

def newton_method(f, f_p, prec=0.01):
    x=1
    x_p=1
    tmp=0

    while(True):
        tmp = x
        x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))
        x_p = tmp
        if (abs(x-x_p) < prec):
            break;

    return x
```

To clarify, function v1 (the first piece of code) works as expected, function v2 (the second) does not.

Why is this the case?
Isn't the original version essentially checking the current `x` versus the `x` from 2 assignments back, rather than the immediately previous `x` ?

Here is the test code I am using:

```
def f(x):
    return x*x - 5

def f_p(x):
    return 2*x

newton_method(f,f_p)
```

**EDIT**

I ended up using this version of the code, which forgoes the `tmp` variable and is much clearer for me, conceptually:

```
# x_1 = x_0 - (f(x_0)/f'(x_0))
# x_n+1 - x_n = precision

def newton_method(f, f_p, prec=0.01):
    x=1
    x_p=1
    tmp=0

    while(True):
        x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))
        if (abs(x-x_p) < prec):
            break;
        x_p = x

    return x
```

Comment: `the function ceases to work as expected.`: How exactly?

Comment: For example, when trying to approximate the solution to x^2 - 5, rather than getting 2.236-ish with the former I get 3.0 with the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `x[i]` be the new value to be computed in an iteration.

### What is happening in version 1:

The statement `x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))` translates to:

`x[i] = x[i-2] - f(x[i-2])/f'(x[i-2])` - ***1***

But according to the actual mathematical formula, it should have been this:

`x[i] = x[i-1] - f(x[i-1])/f'(x[i-1])`

Similarly, `x[i-1] = x[i-2] - f(x[i-2])/f'(x[i-2])` - ***2***

Comparing ***1*** and ***2***, we can see that the `x[i]` in ***1*** is actually `x[i-1]` according to the math formula.

The main point to note here is that `x` and `x_p` are always one iteration apart. That is, `x` is the actual successor to `x_p`, unlike what it might seem by just looking at the code.

Hence, it is working correctly as expected.

### What is happening in version 2:

Just like the above case, the same thing happens at the statement `x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))`.
But by the time we reach `if (abs(x-x_p) < prec)`, `x_p` had changed its value to `temp` = `x` = **`x[i-1]`**.

But as deduced in the case of version 1, `x` too is `x[i-1]` rather than `x[i]`.

So, `abs(x - x_p)` translates to `abs(x[i-1] - x[i-1])`, which will turn out to be 0, hence terminating the iteration.

The main point to note here is that `x` and `x_p` are actually the same values numerically, which always results in the algorithm terminating after just 1 iteration itself.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The code I posted, which as I understand it compares to x from two iterations ago, seems to work as I would expect, while with the if statement after, seems to work incorrectly. Why is this? I will update the question to help explain

Comment: What confuses me is that the x[i-2] version seems to be the one that works while the x[i-1] version does not.

Comment: @Aristides Updated the answer! Hope it's clear this time!

Comment: Much much better, however something still isn't clicking for me. Why is `x[i]` actually `x[i-1]` in the first version?

Comment: Actually `x[i]` is `x[i-1]` in both the versions. If it was `x = x - (f(x)/float(f_p(x)))`, it would have indeed been `x[i]`.  Anyway, don't take the absolute values of the indices too seriously. I just introduced them to establish an ordering between the variables. Their difference is all that matters.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/Machine-Learning/blob/master/newton_raphson/newton.py) for an easier implementation of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This saves the current value of x

```
tmp = x
```

In this statement, the next value of x is created from the current value `x_p`

```
x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))
```

If convergence (eg next value - current value < threshold), break

```
if (abs(x-x_p) < prec):
    break;
```

Set x_p to the next iteration's value

```
x_p = tmp
```

If you pull `x_p = tmp` above the if statement, you are actually checking `x` vs x` from 2 iterations ago, which is not what you want to do. This actually causes weird behavior where the correctness of the outcome is dependent on the starting values. If you start x at you get the correct response whereas if you start with 1, you will not.

To test it out and see why, it can be helpful to add in a print statement as below.

```
def newton_method(f, f_p, prec=0.01):
    x=7
    x_p=1
    tmp=0

    while(True):
        tmp = x
        x = x_p - (f(x_p)/float(f_p(x_p)))
        print (x,x_p,_tmp)
        if (abs(x-x_p) < prec):
            break;
        x_p = tmp
```

---

Are you trying to check X vs X from 2 iterations ago? Or X from the previous iteration of the loop?

If you have `x_p=tmp` before the if statement, `if (abs(x-x_p) < prec):` will check the current value of x versus the previous version of x, instead of x from 2 assignments ago

Comment: okay. so it is indeed checking x from two assignments ago. However why does checking the x from one assignment ago cause the algorithm to fail? That's essentially my question.

Comment: updated question to clarify the nature of my question a little more